# OneNote API returns 19999 error code for any request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I have the application for OneNote users. Some users have error 19999 for any OneNote API request.

Request/response examples:
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "19999",
        "message": "Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2e94b8fb-b43c-4dd6-bb2a-6979fa854718",
            "date": "2019-06-10T03:21:15"
        }
    }
}
```

---

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "19999",
        "message": "Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d650669d-b48f-4d6e-bd18-e0805e79167c",
            "date": "2019-06-10T03:27:53"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenant does not have a SPO license. I will fix the error code to be more specific. Thanks!

Comment: I am having a similar error message while doing a POST on ../onenote/sections/(id)/pages, but we definitely have a license. I've submitted pages this way many times before, using the same program, and even now I can still do some other read and write API calls, e.g. creating a new section in the same notebook.  It's just that page creation always now comes back with 19999. It's the same, except for the date and request id.

`    "innerError": {       "request-id": "a7a797a1-0f5a-477b-8787-2da27cc56a39",       "date": "2020-05-22T19:35:21"    } `

What else would do this?